# A generics way to reduce redundant code

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using a library called [WcfClientProxyGenerator](https://github.com/jweber/WcfClientProxyGenerator) created by @jweber

I used that [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WcfClientProxyGenerator/) to generate a proxy against a service. Everything works and here is a Proxy class:

```
using Silly.Services.CarPark.Logging;
using Silly.Services.CarPark.ServiceContracts.Common.v1;
using log4net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WcfClientProxyGenerator;

namespace Silly.Services.CarPark.Client
{
    public class RequestManager
    {
        private static Log4NetLoggingAdapter systemLogger;
        private static IRequestService proxy = null;

        public RequestManager()
        {
            if (systemLogger == null)
            {
                LoggerSetup.Configure(Constants.ModuleNameForLogging);
                systemLogger = new Log4NetLoggingAdapter(LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(RequestManager)));
            }

            proxy = WcfClientProxy.Create<IRequestService>(c =>
            {
                c.SetEndpoint("BasicHttpBinding_IRequestService");

                c.OnCallBegin += (sender, args) => { };

                c.OnBeforeInvoke += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("{0}.{1} called with parameters: {2}", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName, string.Join(", ", args.InvokeInfo.Parameters)), Core.EventSeverity.Verbose);
                };

                c.OnAfterInvoke += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("{0}.{1} returned value: {2}", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName, args.InvokeInfo.ReturnValue), Core.EventSeverity.Verbose);
                };

                c.OnCallSuccess += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("{0}.{1} completed successfully", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName));
                };

                c.OnException += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("Exception during service call to {0}.{1}: {2}", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName, args.Exception.Message), args.Exception, Core.EventSeverity.Error);
                };
            });
        }
        }
}
```

After a while I found myself with three more services and three more proxies. I see I'm repeating whatever is in the constructor for all four classes and changes are hard to keep track of. Right now the amount of logging is bare but this keeps changing. and there are three more services on the horizon.

Is there a way to use the Class to take the common code out?

Comment: You may want to look into dependency injection. Don't create it in the constructor, ask for it (via parameter) and have *one* outside source that provides it if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency Injection does not address the primary concern about code duplication, because both `systemLogger` and `proxy` are dependent on the type of the service interface, in this case `IRequestService`. So even if you pass these in "from the outside", you would still have different code for *each service interface* that you want to build out, to create the objects that you pass in.

Generics are indeed the way to capture the commonality, because the only difference in the **duplicated** code for each service, is the interface type. I would use a generic base class, and derive each service class from that, something like what I have shown below.

For testability reasons, you might still want to consider use of dependency injection to avoid new-ing up your logging adapater. But that is another question.

**Base class**

```
using log4net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WcfClientProxyGenerator;
using Silly.Services.CarPark.Logging;

namespace Silly.Services.Carpark
{
    public class ClientBase<TClient> where TClient : class
    {
        private static Log4NetLoggingAdapter systemLogger;
        private static TClient proxy;

        public ClientBase(string binding)
        {
            if (systemLogger == null)
            {
                LoggerSetup.Configure(Constants.ModuleNameForLogging);
                systemLogger = new Log4NetLoggingAdapter(LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType()));
            }

            proxy = WcfClientProxy.Create<TClient>(c =>
            {
                c.SetEndpoint(binding);

                c.OnCallBegin += (sender, args) => { };

                c.OnBeforeInvoke += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("{0}.{1} called with parameters: {2}", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName, string.Join(", ", args.InvokeInfo.Parameters)), Core.EventSeverity.Verbose);
                };

                c.OnAfterInvoke += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("{0}.{1} returned value: {2}", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName, args.InvokeInfo.ReturnValue), Core.EventSeverity.Verbose);
                };

                c.OnCallSuccess += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("{0}.{1} completed successfully", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName));
                };

                c.OnException += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("Exception during service call to {0}.{1}: {2}", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName, args.Exception.Message), args.Exception, Core.EventSeverity.Error);
                };
            });
        }

        // The following class property exposes static private var
        // to derived classes, as read-only. 
        protected TClient Proxy { get { return proxy; } }
    }
}
```

**Derived service class**

```
using Silly.Services.CarPark;
using Silly.Services.CarPark.ServiceContracts.Common.v1;
using log4net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WcfClientProxyGenerator;

namespace Silly.Services.CarPark.Client
{
    public class RequestManager : ClientBase<IRequestService>, IRequestService
    {
        public RequestManager() : 
              base("BasicHttpBinding_IRequestService")
        {
        }

        // Implementation of IRequestService methods
        public string Alpha(...) {
          return Proxy.Alpha(...);  
        }

        public void Beta(...) {
              Proxy.Beta(...);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What did you come up yourself? I mean, should be straightforward to do something like this.

The Create method accepts an `Action<IRetryingProxyConfigurator>` as parameter so I would build a method like

```
void ConfigureLogging(IRetryingProxyConfigurator proxyConfigurator)
{
    proxyConfigurator.OnBeforeInvoke += (sender, args) =>
            {
                systemLogger.Write(string.Format("{0}.{1} called with parameters: {2}", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName, string.Join(", ", args.InvokeInfo.Parameters)), Core.EventSeverity.Verbose);
            };

}
```

and call it like:

```
proxy = WcfClientProxy.Create<IRequestService>(c =>
        {
            c.SetEndpoint("BasicHttpBinding_IRequestService");

            ConfigureLogging(c);
        }
```

Refactor out as much duplicate code as you can and a pattern will take shape. You might build a generic factory that accepts the service Interface as a type parameter and do all the templating inside that class.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think this approach. And I've been attempting somewhat of a uglier solutions with generic classes and instead of making the code simple and clean, it got more complex. So I went to generic classes 101. But before doing that, I asked this question. And now I see I was probably wasting my weekend.

Comment: No, I think using generics is definitively the way to go. But it is normally better to refactor in smaller steps, makes it easier to identify the generic parts.

Comment: Can you post your generic attempt? See if we can improve that?

Comment: Let me find one where I had an overall vision instead of extreme tunnel visions

Answer (score 1):

See, given that all bindings are being created here, there has to be a common interface all these services implement. Use that as T and you should be alright without much refactoring

```
 public class GenericManager<T> where T: IBaseInterfaceofWhateverIRequestServiceAndTheRestDeriveFrom
    {
        private static Log4NetLoggingAdapter systemLogger;
        private static T proxy = null;

private void BuildGenericManager<T>(){

if (systemLogger == null)
            {
                LoggerSetup.Configure(Constants.ModuleNameForLogging);
                systemLogger = new Log4NetLoggingAdapter(LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(RequestManager)));
            }
            proxy = WcfClientProxy.Create<T>(c =>
            {
                c.SetEndpoint("BasicHttpBinding_IRequestService");

                c.OnCallBegin += (sender, args) => { };

                c.OnBeforeInvoke += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("{0}.{1} called with parameters: {2}", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName, string.Join(", ", args.InvokeInfo.Parameters)), Core.EventSeverity.Verbose);
                };

                c.OnAfterInvoke += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("{0}.{1} returned value: {2}", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName, args.InvokeInfo.ReturnValue), Core.EventSeverity.Verbose);
                };

                c.OnCallSuccess += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("{0}.{1} completed successfully", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName));
                };

                c.OnException += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    systemLogger.Write(string.Format("Exception during service call to {0}.{1}: {2}", args.ServiceType.Name, args.InvokeInfo.MethodName, args.Exception.Message), args.Exception, Core.EventSeverity.Error);
                };
            });
        }
}
        public GenericManager()
        {
            BuildGenericManager<T>();
        }
}
```

This may not compile and you may need to change things but the intent should be there I think